# Will array form of two different shape BSTs always have non-equal arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

Is it correct that two BSTs that differs in shape (value may differ) have different arrays versions having either,

a) Different array length.

b) If length is same then indexes on which values exist differ. (assume if `A[i]==0` means empty or null child of tree)

I am creating logic to tell if two trees have same shape or not without using recursion. I first convert trees to arrays and then compare there arrays. I am writing this for an online practice challenge question. When I put there given sample trees and some of my own sample trees I get correct results. But when I submit it it says wrong answer. So I was thinking maybe this may not hold true for large trees.

Kindly, tell me If I am looking at things wrong.

-Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It Depends If both of **BST** have same number of Nodes the Array Should be of Size of Full Tree(to avoid any possible errors). So Array Size Should not be used to determine the shape of given tree. Secondly For the tree have same shape (as you wish to guess). The Corresponding Array Indices should be filled, or you can say that both arrays should be equivalent( may be not equal in values).  If these both conditions are verified then both can create same shape.